# Is there a fast way to get all neighbor elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For example, I have a `list` (it can also be a `numpy.array` or anything else, I just wonder a faster way and I don't care the data type) `['a','b','c','d']`, and I want to get `['ab','bc','cd']`.

Of course there's a simple solution such as:

```
letters = list('abcdefghijk')
my_list = [letters[i:i+2] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]
```

And the `my_list` is :

```
[['a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['c', 'd'],
 ['d', 'e'],
 ['e', 'f'],
 ['f', 'g'],
 ['g', 'h'],
 ['h', 'i'],
 ['i', 'j'],
 ['j', 'k']]
```

But I wonder is there any faster way to do this through `numpy` or something else, since I want to do this with a relatively big data, and therefore a simple `for` loop may be costly.

**UPDATE**
Let me sumarrize the answers below now. Very much thanks to the answers so far from @Ehsan and @Andy L. I've done a very simple test of all their solutions with a relatively bigger data through the codes below:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def m1(letters):
    return [letters[i]+letters[i+1] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]

@njit
def m2(letters):
    
    return [letters[i]+letters[i+1] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]

def m3(letters):
    return np.char.add(letters[:-1], letters[1:])

def m4(letters):
    n = len(letters) - 1
    m = np.array(letters[0]).itemsize
    arr = as_strided(letters, shape=(n, 2), strides=(m, m))
    return arr

def test_time(testfunc,args):
    start = time.time()
    testfunc(*args)
    return time.time() - start

# test
ns = [10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
timecost = []
for n in ns:
    input_=np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), size=n)
    cost = [test_time(testfunc, [input_]) for testfunc in [m1, m2, m3,m4]]
    timecost.append(cost)

# result plot
timecost = np.array(timecost)
labels = ['normal','numba.njit','numpy.char.add','numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided']
for i in range(timecost.shape[-1]):
    plt.plot(ns, timecost[:, i], label=labels[i])
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('result.png')
```

The result is:
[image: Horizontal axis: size of data, Vertical axis: time in seconds]

The result shows that with `np.char.add` and `numba`, the performance does work better than the normal method on bigger data, but the performance of `stride_tricks` is even better: the time cost decreases more than two orders of magnitudes.

Comment: _I don't care the data type_: are they all characters? or do you mean to so the same with floats for example?

Comment: @Ehsan My fault. I mean they are all chars but I can accept any types of containers such as `numpy.array` or something else.

Comment: Are you looking to get `['ab','bc','cd']` or `[['a', 'b'],['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'],...`? These are two different formats.

Comment: @Divakar `[['a', 'b'],['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'],...` will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as_strided` from `stride_tricks` library

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

n = len(letters) - 1
m = np.array(letters[0]).itemsize

arr = as_strided(letters, shape=(n, 2), strides=(m, m))

Out[289]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['b', 'c'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['d', 'e'],
       ['e', 'f'],
       ['f', 'g'],
       ['g', 'h'],
       ['h', 'i'],
       ['i', 'j'],
       ['j', 'k']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Very much thanks! This solution works better, the time cost decreases more than two orders of magnitudes. I've updated the time-test result in my post.

Comment: @C.K. Good answer. Be mindful that this provides you with a view. That is why it is basically so fast. If you need to change the strides separately, this might become tricky (for example both `'b'`s refer to the same memory)

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy for it:

```
np.char.add(letters[:-1],letters[1:])
#['ab' 'bc' 'cd' 'de' 'ef' 'fg' 'gh' 'hi' 'ij' 'jk']
```

Another way using numba:

```
@njit
def m2(letters):
  return [letters[i]+letters[i+1] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]
```

---

**Comparison** using `benchit`:

```
def m1(letters):
  return [letters[i]+letters[i+1] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]

@njit
def m2(letters):
  return [letters[i]+letters[i+1] for i in range(len(letters)-1)]

def m3(letters):
  return np.char.add(letters[:-1],letters[1:])

in_ = [np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),size=n) for n in [100,1000,10000,100000]]
```

They all look the same (Note: Not sure if `benchit` does AOT compilation for Numba):

[image]

Comment: Very much thanks to you! I've tested it in the bigger data and the two methods with `numpy` and `numba` do work better than the normal method!